# ModelForm Save Data Giving Error : Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: django, modelform

**Models.py**

```
class ZoneDetail(models.Model):
    zone_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True )
    zone_name = models.CharField(max_length =  20 )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.zone_name

class StateDetail(models.Model):
    zoneId = models.ForeignKey(ZoneDetail)
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length =  20 , choices = STATE_CODE )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.id


class Transaction(models.Model):
    zone                = models.ForeignKey(ZoneDetail)
    state               = models.ForeignKey(StateDetail)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vechile_number
```

Transaction model will store the data on form submission.

**forms.py**

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    zone = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = ZoneDetail.objects.all(),  empty_label = "-- Select Zone --")
    state_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = StateDetail.objects.none())

     class Meta:
         model = Transaction
         fields = ['zone','state_name']
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action = "." >{% csrf_token %}
            <table  border = "0" align="left" margin: "5" > 

                    <tr> 
                        <td style="font-size: 15px; border-bottom: 0px " > {{ form.zone.label_tag }}{{ form.zone }} &nbsp; </td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td style="font-size: 15px; border-bottom: 0px "> {{ form.state_name.label_tag }}{{ form.state_name }}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <input value="Save" title="Save" type="submit" id="btn_save"> 
            </table>    
    </form>
```

Form Submission giving me the error as : Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Comment: How are you expecting users to choose a state? You've set the queryset to None, no options will ever show.

Comment: Initially the state_name set to None, after page get loaded, then for 'Zone' drop-down jquery event  changes the state name to required value, That value is populating fine.

Comment: But the form still thinks there aren't any values to choose from in that field, so whatever you select will be invalid. You'd need to change the queryset on submit as well.